# How to create the exe file using python script with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, build, exe, cx-freeze

```
create_product
    src
        common
            util.py
        config
            config.properities
        templates
            template1.txt
        create_product.py
        setup.py
    Python36
```

I am using the above project directory structure in python. And I'm using cx_freeze.
I able build the exe with below command.

```
python setup.py build
```

I am using below script as setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
executables = [Executable("create_products.py", base=base)]

setup(
    name = "createproduct",
    version = "1.0.0",
    executables = [Executable("create_products.py",base="Win32GUI")]
    )
```

While build i'm getting this,

```
Missing modules:
? Cookie imported from requests.compat
? OpenSSL.SSL imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? OpenSSL.crypto imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? StringIO imported from requests.compat, urllib3.packages.six
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _scproxy imported from urllib.request
? _winreg imported from platform, requests.utils
? backports.ssl_match_hostname imported from urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
? cookielib imported from requests.compat
? cryptography imported from requests, urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509 imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.x509 imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? cryptography.x509.extensions imported from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, requests.adapters, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from getpass, http.server, netrc, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? simplejson imported from requests.compat
? socks imported from urllib3.contrib.socks
? termios imported from getpass, tty
? urllib.getproxies imported from requests.compat
? urllib.getproxies_environment imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass imported from requests.compat
? urllib.proxy_bypass_environment imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote imported from requests.compat
? urllib.quote_plus imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote imported from requests.compat
? urllib.unquote_plus imported from requests.compat
? urllib.urlencode imported from requests.compat
? urllib2 imported from requests.compat
? urllib3.packages.six.moves imported from urllib3.connectionpool, urllib3.response, urllib3.util.queue, urllib3.util.response
? urllib3.packages.six.moves.http_client imported from urllib3.connection, urllib3.exceptions
? urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse imported from urllib3.poolmanager, urllib3.request
? urlparse imported from requests.compat
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.
```

And i'm getting below error when I run the exe file

[image]

How to avoid this problem?